# Why images taking too much time delay while loading from server in android?

Tags: android

I am facing some issue regarding image loading. I am using image loader to load images from server, but it takes too much time delay to load images.
Here is my code for imageload:

Initialize the DisplayImageOptions.

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.user_icon)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.user_icon)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading).build();
```

And to load image:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(base64Image, holder.profile_image, options);
```

Comment: Umm... You have slow internet? You cache to disk? Not clear what answer you want.

Comment: what are the sizes of your images you were loading?

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, but Internet speed is 2-3 Mbps,

Comment: #Camahalan Royette Image Sizes around 200-300 kb

Comment: tryout using libraries like glide/picasso

Comment: "but Internet speed is 2-3 Mbps". You realize that is slow, right? It takes half a second to load just one 200kB file

Comment: And 300 kb at 2Mbps is 1.2 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the method resetVideBeforeLoading. Check a sample that I'm usually applying:

```
// Create a public utility class

public static ImageLoaderConfiguration getConfig(Context context) {
    return new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800)
            .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(context.getCacheDir()))
            .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
            .diskCacheFileCount(100)
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context))
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
            .build();
}

public static DisplayImageOptions getOptions() {
    return new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(false) // Default
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) // Default
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // Default
            .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()) // Default
            .handler(new Handler()) // Default
            .build();
}
```

And to use:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(Utils.getConfig(context));
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
    imageUrl,
    mImageView,
    Utils.getOptions(), new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
            // Show loader
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            // Show error message
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {

            // Hide loader
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: "resetVideBeforeLoading" is worked for me . Thanks buddy.